# Why can't John Constantine drive?

Tags: hellblazer

In the original *[Hellblazer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellblazer)* comics John Constantine seems to persistently rely on hitchhiking to various locations, taking public transport ("*Christ, I wish I could **drive.** Bloody public transport's a **nightmare**"*), getting taxis or calling in favours from his sidekick Chaz in order to get to where he needs to go.

John seems multi-talented in other ways and has plenty of access to vehicles and potential driving instructors as well as having no compunction about breaking the law in emergencies, if the mere lack of a licence is all that's standing in his way.

**Why can't he drive?**

[image]
<sub><sup>[Hellblazer #7](https://hellblazer.fandom.com/wiki/Hellblazer_issue_7)</sup></sub>

Comment: Please note that I'm not referring to the rebooted New 52 comics where he does drive, only those properties (e.g. the original comics and maybe the film) where he doesn't

Comment: Not authoritative, but Constantine is nearly always on a bender. I suspect he learned he has no drinking limits a long time ago, and having a car and being able to drive it would only end up causing him more problems when he gets hammered.

Comment: @SillybutTrue - And while that's not untrue, he doesn't even drive in dire emergencies and while sober(ish)

Comment: I got nothing; dire emergencies are the likeliest of times he goes on benders?

Comment: I wonder if traditional Londoners are like traditional New Yorkers, proud of their inability to drive.

Comment: @Broklynite - He's originally from Liverpool, although lives in London from his teens onwards

Comment: Conceivably he means that it's *not practical* to drive; that he had nowhere to park a car and despite their inconveniences, other means are more practical.

Comment: @Mary - Well, no. He doesn't drive even when it would be eminently useful to do so (for example, when getting away from dangerous enemies)

Comment: @Broklynite, not proud of it as such, but it's unnecessary within zone 3, and these days impractical to drive inwards of zone 4 anyway as you have to know exactly where you can park before you leave, so it just isn't important.

Comment: **MILLIGAN:** *And who says that John can’t drive? He simply chooses not to.* - https://www.dccomics.com/blog/2018/10/30/peter-milligan-and-editor-shelly-bond-talk-hellblazer. Massive retcons in his run though...

Comment: @Valorum  Its being useful would not allow him to buy a car in a minute, so the question of where to put it would still arise.  (And if he has a car, it doesn't do much good if it's parked somewhere because he knew there was no parking where he was going.)

Answer (score 7):

### A Speculative Answer — Frank William "Chas" Chandler was a way to ground Constantine and work in writer Jamie Delano’s life experiences

In comic book tropes, the “sidekick” is an important feature of the story, usually intended to humanize the superhuman.

With Constantine, himself, originating as a supporting character in Swamp Thing, Hellblazer v. 1 gave writer Jamie Delano a blank slate chance to provide this to John Constantine.

In creating the narrative that Chas wasn’t just a “right hand man” to Constantine, but making him a London cabbie, it satisfied the conceit of Constantine not driving.

This conceit allows Chas to show up any time, for nearly any reason to fit Delano’s story, as Constantine could always relay on public transportation too.

Additionally, [Jamie Delano was a London cabbie](http://invictaindiearts.blogspot.com/2020/06/exclusive-interview-to-english-writer.html?m=1):

> But, I am Jamie Delano; I was born in Northampton; I had a standard UK education for the time (1954-72), and elected not to attend university, but instead worked for ten years at a variety of regular jobs – bookshop manager, librarian, timber-yard worker, ***taxi driver/despatcher*** – while harbouring a deep-seated belief that I would one day be a writer (if not necessarily a “terrific” one), before actually becoming one (professionally) in the early 1980s.

This would allow Delano a greater chance to write what he knows, further humanizing *Hellblazer*, using Chas as his surrogate.

[Hellblazer wiki discussed this further](https://hellblazer.fandom.com/wiki/Jamie_Delano):

> He created John's "sidekick" Chas as a homage to his own life experience - Delano was a London cab driver for nearly seven years, before he started writing comics for British publishers, on Alan Moore's recommendation.

Comment: I did think of that, but in the earlier comics (Swamp Thing and Hellblazers 1-10) Chaz is barely present. He certainly doesn't add a 'grounding' element until much later in the run

Comment: Well, IIRC Chas was Delano’s creation. That is, I don’t know if Constantine’s non-driving was ever a thing within _Swamp Thing_ before Hellblazer #1 in 1988, nor was Chas a character before Delano’s _Hellblazer_ debut; if these are true, then I more strongly believe any answer to your question is likely to be a Delano-centric reason.

Comment: He does drive relatively early on, in Hellblazer 30. When a character remarks that they didn't know he could drive, he replies that he can't (despite that he evidently can)

Comment: It’s a ESB “Han Solo Jedi Master” situation.  There is driving and then there is barely getting by with mechanical operation of cranking ignitions and pushing pedals; dogs have been known to get cars into gear.

Comment: He does effectively drive a considerable distance though.

Comment: Beginner’s luck.

Comment: I guess you could put it down to monkey-see, monkey-do. He can operate a vehicle in the same way that a child could work a nuclear reactor after sitting in the control room for a few days.

Answer (score 0):

He is seen to drive towards the end of the original 300 issue run, though this is probably an inside joke as His fiance had previously noted that He probably could drive and was just lazy. This would suit the character.

Comment: At the start of the run he repeatedly states that he can't drive. Him driving seems to be a Peter Milligan reboot retcon after he took over the series around issue #250. They also gave him a completely new back-story, missing fingers and a new sister